# Drop triggers for all tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have multiple triggers, all being the same trigger, but on different tables e.g.

```
  tgname         |          trigger_table           
------------------------+----------------------------------
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548180000
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548187200
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548162000
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548190800
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548183600
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548172800
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548111600
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548136800
 updated_agg_trigger    | forecasts.forecast_1548129600
```

How can I delete all `updated_agg_trigger`-triggers on all tables with a single command?

P.S. I don't want to delete ALL triggers, just the `updated_agg_trigger`-triggers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699480/postgresql-delete-multiple-rows-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run  dynamic statement looping through `information_schema.triggers`.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
l_trig_name TEXT := 'updated_agg_trigger';
l_schema    TEXT := 'forecasts';
rec record;
BEGIN

for rec IN
(
  SELECT event_object_table as table_name
      ,trigger_schema as schema_name
      ,trigger_name
   FROM  information_schema.triggers
      WHERE  trigger_name   = l_trig_name
       AND trigger_schema   = l_schema
 ) 
   LOOP
        EXECUTE format ('DROP TRIGGER %I 
                ON %I.%I', rec.trigger_name,rec.schema_name,rec.table_name);
   END LOOP;

END $$;
```

Comment: Thought it worked, but it didn't. I'm getting ERROR:  relation "forecast_1548180000" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TRIGGER updated_agg_trigger ON forecast_1548180000"

Comment: Okay, so I just had to add the schema in the `DROP TRIGGER...` format i.e. `EXECUTE format ('DROP TRIGGER %I ON forecasts.%I', l_trig_name,rec.table_name);`

Comment: @Jesper : Yes, it was my mistake as well. I've changed my code, which is more generalised