# PostgreSQL - Delete data from two table using one query?

Tags: postgresql

How I can delete data from several tables by one queries in SQL?
I trying, but not working:

```
DELETE FROM "paginationsCount" AND
DELETE FROM "paginationsUrl" AND
DELETE FROM "taskStatus" AND
DELETE FROM "sessionId";
```

or

```
DELETE FROM "paginationsCount";
DELETE FROM "paginationsUrl";
DELETE FROM "taskStatus";
DELETE FROM "sessionId";
```

Comment: You need four DELETE statements if you want to delete from four tables. You can put them into a transaction if you want to make that atomic.

Comment: If those tables have foreign key relationships a FK definition with `on delete cascade` might do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql delete multiple rows from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699480/postgresql-delete-multiple-rows-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

We can run a delete in a CTE and use `returning` to use the id's of the deleted rows in a subsequent query, which can be SELECT, INSERT or DELETE.

> ```
> create table table1(id1 int, id2 int);
> create table table2(id2 int, id3 int);
> create table table3(id3 int, id4 int);
> create table table4(id4 int, def int);
> insert into table1 values(11,21),(12,22);
> insert into table2 values(21,31),(22,32);
> insert into table3 values(31,41),(32,42);
> insert into table4 values(41,1),(42,2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1;
> select * from table2;
> select * from table3;
> select * from table4;
> ```
>
> ```
> id1 | id2
> --: | --:
>  11 |  21
>  12 |  22
>
> id2 | id3
> --: | --:
>  21 |  31
>  22 |  32
>
> id3 | id4
> --: | --:
>  31 |  41
>  32 |  42
>
> id4 | def
> --: | --:
>  41 |   1
>  42 |   2
> ```

> ```
> with 
> del4 as (
> delete from table4 where def = 1
> returning id4),
> del3 as (
> delete from table3 where id4 in(select id4 from del4)
> returning id3),
> del2 as (
> delete from table2 where id3 in(select id3 from del3)
> returning id2)
> delete from table1 where id2 in(select id2 from del2);
> ```

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from table1;
> select * from table2;
> select * from table3;
> select * from table4;
> ```
>
> ```
> id1 | id2
> --: | --:
>  12 |  22
>
> id2 | id3
> --: | --:
>  22 |  32
>
> id3 | id4
> --: | --:
>  32 |  42
>
> id4 | def
> --: | --:
>  42 |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=82fe2f5fedfde287e3bbb7c92f7ed8f5)*